# Updating Array Property Using Custom Setters in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, properties, setter

I have a class where I want to use Storyboard to set up to 4 UIColors for a CAGradientLayer.

I am using an array to keep track of the UIColors being set from the Storyboard.

When the user sets a color, I want to add it to the the array and if they set the color to nothing (is that even possible?), I want to remove it from the array.

The gradient layer will have anywhere from 2 to 4 colors.

The code below is what I came up with, but I'm looking for something a bit cleaner if possible.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var gradientColors = [UIColor]()


    @IBInspectable var color1Value: UIColor?
        {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradientLayer()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var color2Value: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradientLayer()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var color3Value: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradientLayer()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var color4Value: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.updateGradientLayer()
        }
    }


    func updateGradientLayer() {
        gradientColors.removeAll()
        gradientColors.append(color1Value!)
        gradientColors.append(color2Value!)
        gradientColors.append(color3Value!)
        gradientColors.append(color4Value!)

        gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the use of the CAGradientLayer but I would recommend creating an actual array of optional colors and using `flatMap` to eliminate the missing color values. Something like this.

```
var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientColors: [UIColor?] = [nil, nil, nil, nil] {
  didSet {
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors.flatMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

Then access the gradientColors array by index and any change to any index will update the gradient layer.

```
viewController.gradientColors[1] = .red
viewController.gradientColors = [.black, nil, .blue, .yellow]
```

My original reply did not handle the requirement for each color to be IBInspectable. If needed, you could do something like this but now you are back to a nearly equivalent number of code lines.

```
@IBInspectable var gradientColor1: UIColor? {
  didSet {
    gradientColors[0] = gradientColor1
  }
}
// ... for other colors.
```